# add variable to ternary operator Php

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to summarize this ternary operator and add a new variable to the result (in a single line)

```
$names= "Joe";
$channel ="joe";

 $user_alt= $names ? $names : "";
 $user_alt= $user_alt." @".$channel;
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
   <img src=""  alt="Joe @joe" />
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what about this `$user_alt= $names ? $names." @".$channel : "";`

Comment: Do you mean `$user_alt= ($names ? $names : "") ." @".$channel;`

Comment: @Nick I liked yours. feel free to post your answer to mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
$user_alt= ($names ? $names : "") ." @".$channel;
```

Note the necessity of the brackets around the ternary operator as `:` has lower precedence than `.`.

Comment: A pleasure. Thanks for the rep.